# Unable to get notification by FCM on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have already add APNs certificate on firebase..but when i send notification from FCM my device not showing any notification and also InstanceID and messageID gives null in the output

here is my app delegate.m code

```html
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    sleep(3);
     SplitsVC*log=[[SplitsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplitsVC" bundle:nil];
    
    self.navVC=[[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:log];
    
    [self.navVC.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navVC];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Add observer to listen for the token refresh notification.
    // Register for remote notifications
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }
    
    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]
    
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}

// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    
    // Print message ID.
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);
    
    // Pring full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);
    
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];
    
    // TODO: If necessary send token to appliation server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
}

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]
```

and this is output-
[image]

Comment: please tell me solution....

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the certificate which is up on firebase and the one you are using in xcode is same . And also please try to look at the documentation of Firebase.

Comment: sir my project signing code identity not getting the existing certificate so how can i solve this issue?..please sir guid me i already waste two days

Comment: Please try to download your certificate and provisioning profile from https://developer.apple.com/ and upload same (.p12) certificate in firebase cloud messaging section.